# Is it possible to flush all stored information?

Tags: python

Say I've written a python script defining some classes, functions, variables, and constructing some objects. I open it from the command prompt or bash terminal with:

`python3 -i /home/me/scripts/myScript.py` or `python -i c:\users\me\scripts`

Now I've go an environment to play with. But after some tinkering I discover I need one of the functions to act differently.

Obviously the solution is to modify and save the script file, exit the console to the terminal (or close it all entirely, starting from a fresh process), and reopen the file.

But in the interest of saving a few steps I wonder if there is a way for me to flush all that data from the current session using a command. That way I could use:

`exec(open(r"c:\u\m\s\m.p").read())` or `exec(open("/h/m/s/m.p").read())`

from my command history to reload the new version of the script.

This, combined with an automatic procedure for flushing and reading would really make things a lot simpler for me.

**EDIT** I'm open to a lengthy solution, so long as its programmatic.

Comment: If you refactor so the script is a module you import, you could use importlib.reload() https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far as I can tell there doesn't seem to be anyway to flush an active python session using a command. However I recently discovered the 'Spyder' IDE distributed with '[Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)'. Anyone that doesn't know about Spyder ought to. It isn't very pretty a first, but after tinkering with panel and menu location and toggle, it can look very pretty. But more to the point, it has a few features right out of the box that realy make it useful for the above mentioned task.

First it has none, one, or multiple python sessions running internally ready to interact with the currently focused script document. Also it has a panel dedicated to analyzing and listing elements from the memory of the currently focused python session, including variables and objects. And finally, the user may select these items to modify and/or remove them. Removing all of them effectively cleans the current session.